# Ошибка при закрытии 2 формы

Tags: delphi, pascal

Код следующий:

```
procedure TForm1.RazmeschenieButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Sum1, Sum2, A:Int64;
  index, n, k, b:Integer;
begin
if (not Assigned(Form2)) then Form2:=TForm2.Create(Self) else
if (VvodNRazmeschenieEdit.Text ='') or (VvodKRazmeschenieEdit.Text ='')
then i:=Form2.ShowModal else
n:=StrToInt(VvodNRazmeschenieEdit.Text);
k:=StrToInt(VvodKRazmeschenieEdit.Text);
Sum1:=1;
for index:=1 to n do
Sum1:=Sum1*index;
b:=n-k;
Sum2:=1;
for index:=1 to b do
Sum2:=Sum2*index;
A:=Round(Sum1/Sum2);
VyvodRazmeschenieEdit.Text:=IntToStr(A);
end;
```

Если в поле Edit не ввести значение, то при нажатии кнопки вылетает 2 форма. На 2 форме лишь одна кнопка со следующим кодом:

```
procedure TForm2.CloseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form2.Close;
end;
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии кнопки на 2 форме я получаю следующую ошибку:

> [Warning] Unit1.pas(119): Variable 'n' might not have been initialized.

2 форма находится в списке доступных форм. Прошу помочь.

Comment: отформатируй текст кода. Невозможно так нормально выявлять ошибку.

Comment: @Азерос, это не ошибка, а предупреждение, что вы не инициализировали n. Инициализируйте ее. Ну и поможет если вы сможете ответить на вопрос чему будет равно n если значение в ваших edit'ах будет не заполнено. Допустим, компилятор решил не обнулять вам n, а оставить в ней мусор (например, 82345 или -8). как будет работать ваша программа? дальше можете проверить что будет если в edit'ы ввести например 'привет', что будет с вашей программой?

Comment: В поле VvodRazmeschenieEdit.Text можно вводить только числовые значения и бэкспейс. На это есть процедуры. Если n не заполнено, должна вылетать 2 форма. Если же я присвою значению n какое-либо значение (к примеру 1), то вылетит следующие ошибки:
[Warning] Unit1.pas(123): Variable 'n' might not have been initialized (Переменная 'n', возможно, не была инициализирована).
[Hint] Unit1.pas(240): Value assigned to 'n' never used (Значение присваиваемое 'n' никогда не использовалось).

Comment: В смысле отформатировать текст кода? Если я всё удалю и напишу по новой, это не поможет мне решить проблему.

Comment: если вылетит форма, то чему будет равно `n` после ее закрытия? проблема у вас в логике. код, который у вас написан, будет выполняться после того как форма закроется, с неизвестным значением n (по факту там будет 0). Это не ошибка с точки зрения компилятора, а ошибка с точки зрения логики вашей программы. Все переменные должны быть инициализированы вами. То, что вы получаете hint на неиспользуемое значение - это вы не в том месте ее инициализируете, там это значение не нужно. вам говорят, что в 123 строке у вас n может иметь не инициализированное значение, а вы инициализируете зачем-то в 240.

Comment: я кажется начинаю догадываться. после else должен быть begin, а перед end еще один end. да? это как раз следствие неотформатированного кода. если бы вы его отформатировали, то увидели бы (ну по крайней мере нам было бы понятно) какие блоки кода когда должны выполняться и где вы что забыли.

Answer (score 1):

Если по вопросу, тогда присвоение переменной n будет только в тех случаях когда у нас ни разу не была создана форма и есть значения в полях VvodNRazmeschenieEdit или VvodKRazmeschenieEdit. Во всех остальных случаях значение переменной не присваивается. Поэтому компилятор и предупреждает что могут быть ситуации когда у нас в переменную ничего не запишется, а будет какой то "мусор". В зависимости от задачи - переменную можно инициализировать просто присвоив n:= 0 в начале процедуры. Но все упирается в логику работы. Все таки не ясно почему переменная n попала под else а k нет.

На счет форматирования. Намного удобнее читается если отформатировать по неким стандартам.(Кстати начиная с какой то версии Delphi есть функция авто форматирования Ctrl+D):

```
var
    Sum1, Sum2, A: Int64;
    index, n, k, b: Integer;
    I: Integer;
begin
    if (not Assigned(Form2)) then
        Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self)
    else
        if (VvodNRazmeschenieEdit.Text = '') or (VvodKRazmeschenieEdit.Text = '') then
            i := Form2.ShowModal
        else
          n := StrToInt(VvodNRazmeschenieEdit.Text);

    k := StrToInt(VvodKRazmeschenieEdit.Text);
    Sum1 := 1;
    for index := 1 to n do
        Sum1 := Sum1 * index;

    b := n - k;
    Sum2 := 1;

    for index := 1 to b do
        Sum2 := Sum2 * index;

    A := Round(Sum1 / Sum2);
    VyvodRazmeschenieEdit.Text := IntToStr(A);
```

В таком случае видно когда будет присвоено значение переменной n.

Рассмотрим дальше код:
I. Переменная I не определена. Она глобальная?

```
i := Form2.ShowModal
```

Это выражение нигде не используется, а результат возвращает [ModalResult](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TCustomForm_ModalResult.html).
Грубо говоря, если вы на второй форме вместо Form2.Close; напишите

```
ModalResult := MrOk;
```

тогда в переменную I запишется MrOk или 1 :-)

II. С **W1036 Variable 'n' might not have been initialized разобрались выше**.

III. Код проверки создания формы будет выполняться всегда, его лучше вынести и создавать раньше или каким то боком немного переделать логику.

```
if (not Assigned(Form2)) then
    Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self)
```

IV. Используйте функции для расчетов. Для отдельных функция потом можно будет написать тест, который проверяет правильно она работает или нет. К примеру:

```
function Calulate(const N, K : Integer): Int64;

    function Multiply(StartValue, Counter : Int64): Int64;
    var
      I: Integer;
    begin
       Result := StartValue;
       for I := 0 To n do
          Result := Result * I;
    end;

Var
  Sum1, Sum2: Int64;
begin
   Sum1 := Multiply(1, N);
   Sum2 := Multiply(1, N - K);
   Result := Round(Sum1 / Sum2);
end;
```

И все, вызов бы свелся к коду:

```
// инициализация n и k
...
VyvodRazmeschenieEdit.Text := IntToStr(Calulate(N,K));
```

V. Вам повезло что вы используете конструкцию вида TForm2.Create(Self), в таком случае управление жизнью объекта перекладывается на Form1. Если надумаете сами создавать и уничтожать объекты - почитайте об [утечке памяти при написании кода](http://mirsovetov.net/?s=%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8).